# JBoss hangs on startup eclipse

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

im starting jboss(7.1.0) from eclipse(Kepler), but keeps freezing on starting state..
When after timeout, it gives a error saying that Jboss didnt start..

If i start Jboss from command line, works fine.

Just for info, im using java6, for runtime

Comment: please add server log.

Comment: Any error message? My guess is possibly the management client can't connect to the server. Errors or the log would be helpful though.